# QML: Is there any reason to set a context property instead of setting a property on the root object, when the latter way has advantages?

Tags: qt, properties, qml

Consider this setting of a context property:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("text", "hey");
```

And this qml code:

```
Text {
    text: text
}
```

This doesn't work as expected, because of the name shadowing.

One fix is to name the context property `_text` - then there's no problem. But I don't want to have to remember this naming convention (both to remember to use it, and to remember what it means when I read it).

Another fix is to change the context property into a property on the root object:

```
engine.rootObjects()[0]->setProperty("text", "hey"); // [1]
```

and in the QML:

```
text: window.text
```

Is there any reason to avoid the latter way when it seems so good?

Answer (score 4):

Setting a context property has one disadvantage - it requires recompilation of the C++ code. Naturally, that's a non-issue if you are exposing a C++ object, which is the typical and only logical use case.

It may be seen as an advantage that the context property can be available before the root object is created, but in most cases it will work equally well if it is just a property of the root object. And I clarify that "most cases" here means that object properties are typically not being set from C++ and not being used in initial bindings, since obviously, if you do that, the initial binding will fail to resolve the property when the object is created, before the property is being set. Also note that when creating QML object form C++, you can use the two step process - prepare the object, then set any properties and so on, and only then complete the object creation, which will delay binding evaluations, so you won't have that problem.

Another possible advantage is that you can have more than one root object, thus if the property is in the root context, then all root objects and their subsequent children will be able to resolve it.

Another possible advantage - when you set a context property, you typically get assistance from the IDE, as that object is now known to be out there, so you will have auto-complete for that property name. It sometimes works for parent object properties as well, but it is a hit-or-miss.

As for the speed of access, I am not so sure that a context property would be faster than root object property. I haven't tested it, but it is just logical. Any object property is a de-facto context property, as each object has its own context. Considering that, as you recently discovered, context properties can be shadowed by object properties, it is thus logical to conclude that a context property lookup simply goes down the object contexts until it finds that property rather than going straight to it, so if anything, resolving context properties should be a tad slower than resolving root object properties, because they go one step deeper.

Comment: The "more than one root object" argument is compelling, thanks. About speed of access, I've removed this sentence from my own answer so you can remove your last paragraph. And sure enough, in my question I meant exposing *C++* objects, and not values that I could set without C++. The simple string example is just for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Until line *[1]* has been executed, `window.text` is undefined, so at first, you get an error message on the console (though once it gets to executing line *[1]*, the text is displayed). But if you use a context property, you're free to create it before loading the QML file, which removes the problem.